# How can i download a Form created with Form io?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, formio

I've created a pdf form using form.io and i wanted to download it after the submission, is there any way to archieve this?

```
// jsonLoaded contains the json of the components
            Formio.createForm(document.getElementById('formio'), jsonLoaded, {
                readOnly: true,
                renderMode: 'pdf'
            })
```

I tried watching the form.io documentation, but i couldn't come up with anything.